# Is it unprofessional to say "Sorry for my English"?

Tags: word-choice, formality, letter-writing

First of all I am sorry if this is wrong forum for this question.

I have come in a situation recently where I was needed to write a mail to a foreign company. And as you probably noticed by now my English is bad so I was wondering, is it unprofessional to say

> (a) Excuse my English
>   or
>   (b) Sorry for my English

at the end of an e-mail?

Comment: You *could* say: *"I apologize for not being [word-perfect](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/word-perfect) in English"* but this might conflict with the style of your letter, and the reader might think: "The letter was fine, why is he pointing out he's made mistakes or errors?" It's a bit of a double-edged sword.

Comment: I agree with Mari-Lou's comment.  Your English may not be perfect but, as far as we can see from the few words in your question, it is not poor. As a lot of correspondence in English is written by non-natives speakers nowadays, people do not expect perfection in language, and do not normally think any the worse of people who do not write perfect English. Of course, if you are sending such things as an important legal document, technical instructions or marketing material to promote your company/product, then don't risk poor English; get your material professionally translated into English.

Comment: *For* works better with something one has done, or such. *About* may be a better choice in this case: *Sorry about my (poor) English.* Why not be more explicit and include the most important part, "poor"?

Comment: By say "poor" here, one is only showing modesty and not making some kind of a confession or speaking an actual fact. As such it's fine to say so.

Comment: I see, I guess in my case there is no harm writing it. @Kris, I see your point but saying that my English is poor can make reader get wrong opinion, like the writer is insecure about his skills and thinks low of himself. Mari-Lou A's version is better because it doesn't show me as some ignorant, arrogant person or someone with low self confidence.

Comment: I would actually put such a remark at the _)beginning_ of the email, not at the end. Putting it at the beginning prepares the reader for not-perfect English, and can lead to a "that wasn't too bad" or "good he warned me" reaction. Putting it at the end may lead to a "what does he mean" or "yeah, now he tells me" reaction.

Comment: @oerkelens good tip! To follow up Kris's idea there's the expression "my poor command of English" But it's *very* formal, I think. But it has the advantage of making you sound modest/humble at the same time.

Comment: This might be a question for a sister site like Workplace, but it doesn't really belong here. As far as the English language is concerned, you can start the email with "dear stinkers" and end it with a death threat. This is about manners, not language, and not specific to English, either. You'd have the same question about Russian or Nahuatl.

Comment: [SE Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: oh well ofc, SE Workplace I forgot about that one. Thanks. Should I delete this question here or?

Answer (score 6):

As a UK company we receive thousands of emails and letters every day from foreign companies selling services. The inclusion of "excuse my English" or "sorry for my English" would normally lead to an email or letter being immediately disregarded as spam due to the sheer amount of communications we receive that say this and then try to sell sub-standard services. This isn't really a comment regarding grammar but I feel it may answer your question better.

Comment: If the sentence was phrased differently, i.e., *apologize*, would it make any difference to your spam filters?

Comment: In terms of human spam filtering I would say no, it is the same as saying "sorry my service isn't very good" when starting a description of your service. In the context that this question is asked I would say the only solution is for the email to be written in good enough English that there is need to apologise in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I would say, "English is not my mother tongue; please excuse any errors on my part."